# Is it possible to run grunt on an Ubuntu (LAMP) webserver?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webserver, gruntjs

I was just wondering if that would be possible since node can run on servers and Grunt largely depends on node.

Comment: grunt can only run on non-standard web servers.

Comment: Seriously though, what is a "standard" web server ?

Comment: @adeneo, Yeah that's a little vague. Let's say a LAMP stack on ubuntu.

Comment: As Grunt is a javascript task runner, I'd say no, you can't run it on a lamp stack in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Adeneo didn't post it as an answer:

> As Grunt is a javascript task runner, I'd say no, you can't run it on a lamp stack in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

May be cause of new version of grunt you need to install grunt-cli globally in addition to grunt installation?

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not an answer to my question. I think you misunderstood it.

Comment: @Sam what is your question?  You can run grunt on Ubuntu, assuming you have node and grunt installed.

Comment: My question is if it is possible to run grunt remotely, on a headless LAMP server install of ubuntu. But I guess you would need a node install for that..